# Laravel 5.3 : Method [show] does not exist

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

When post my form to the controller, the laravel shows this error:

> Method PTA_OIMS\Http\Controllers\InstructionsController::show() does
>   not exist in
>   /home/rad/public_html/pta_oims/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:333

this is my web.php file:

```
Route::post('instructions/view','InstructionsController@view')->name('view');
Route::post('instructions/assign','InstructionsController@assign');
Route::get('instructions/sent','InstructionsController@sent')->name('sent');
Route::post('instructions/reject','InstructionsController@reject')->name('reject');
Route::resource('instructions','InstructionsController');
```

and blade view:

```
 <form action=" {{url('instructions/assign')}}"
```

Became more complete:

InstructionsController and added show(),view() and assign() method

```
public function show()
{
    return 'show() method done!!';
}
```

view() method

```
public function view(Request $request)
{
    $boxes = $this->getBoxesList();
    $id = $request->input('id');
    $data = Kartable::where('id', '=', $id)
        ->with('instruction')
        ->first();
    if ($data->view_date == NULL) {
        $this->insertViewDate($id);
    }

    return view('instructions.view', array('data' => $data, 'boxes' => $boxes));
}
```

view blade file, The form that sends the data to assign() method:

```
<form method="POST" action=" {{url('instructions/assign')}}" 
    class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-toggle="validator">

    {{csrf_field()}}
```

assign() method

```
public function assign(Request $input)
{
    try {

        $inst_id = $input->input('inst_id');
//        $childsInsts = Instructions::where('parent_id', '=', $inst_id)
//             ->where('status', '=', 0)
//             ->get();
        $formData = $input->all();
        $step = 0;
        foreach ($formData['box'] as $box) {
            foreach ($box as $id_reciver)
                DB::transaction(function () use ($formData, $inst_id, $id_reciver, $step) {
                    $kar = new Kartable();

                    $kartable_id = $formData['kartable_id'];
                    $current_box = $formData['current_box'];
                    $kar->inst_id = $inst_id;
                    $kar->parent_id = $kartable_id;
                    $kar->id_sender = $current_box;
                    $kar->id_reciver = $id_reciver;
                    $kar->status = 1;
                    $kar->save(); // insert for new record of kartable
                    $step += 1;
                    if ($step < 2) {
                        $kartable = new Kartable();
                        $kartable
                            ->where('id', '=', $kartable_id)
                            ->update(['status' => 3]); //change status of old row kartable
                    }
                });

            return redirect()->route('instructions.index');
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked that in your "InstructionsController" has an "show" method?

Because you're declaring Route::resource('instructions','InstructionsController');
Then you Laravel assumes that the controller has the methods below:

[image]

Check [this docs from Laravel bro.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers)

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is because you don't have a `method=` on your `<form>` tag which will cause the form to be submitted with a `GET` request and seeing as you have a `Route::resource` set up it will assume you're trying to access the show method.

Change your form tag to be:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('instructions/assign') }}">
```

Also, don't forget to add:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

inside your form so that you don't get a `TokenMismatchException`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

need to define your router.

```
Route::get('instructions/show','InstructionsController@show')->name('show');
```